# Efficiently splitting pandas rows based on relative values/ dates

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I have the following df

```
import pandas as pd
foo = pd.DataFrame({'start_date':['2019-09-30', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-02-02'], 
                    'end_date': ['2019-10-13', '2020-01-30', '2020-01-03', '2020-03-03'], 
                    'index': [1, 1, 3, 4],
                    'quantity': [100, 200, 113, 3123]})
```

I am hoping to convert this df from a start and end date to a single column with a date column and evenly splitting out the quantity.

The method I currently have and that works is:

```
import datetime as dt
df = pd.DataFrame()
count = 0
foo['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(foo['start_date'], errors='coerce')
foo['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(foo['end_date'], errors='coerce')

for i, row in foo.iterrows():
    count = count + 1
    start = row['start_date']
    end = row['end_date']
    span = end - start + dt.timedelta(days=1)
        
    #loop through start and end dates. 
    for d in range(span.days):
        day = start + dt.timedelta(days=d)
        df = df.append({'index': row['index'],
                        'date': day,
                         'quantity': row['quantity'] / span.days,
                         'line_item': count},
                          ignore_index=True)

print(df)
    date  index  line_item    quantity
    0  2019-09-30    1.0        1.0    7.142857
    1  2019-10-01    1.0        1.0    7.142857
    2  2019-10-02    1.0        1.0    7.142857
    3  2019-10-03    1.0        1.0    7.142857
    4  2019-10-04    1.0        1.0    7.142857
    ..        ...    ...        ...         ...
    72 2020-02-28    4.0        4.0  100.741935
    73 2020-02-29    4.0        4.0  100.741935
    74 2020-03-01    4.0        4.0  100.741935
    75 2020-03-02    4.0        4.0  100.741935
    76 2020-03-03    4.0        4.0  100.741935
```

As you can imagine with iterows this process quickly becomes very slow when the initial df I am working with is a few ten thousand rows.
As the start and end dates don't follow a particular pattern, there is no way of using the methods I've currently seen, either explode or resample

Small adjustments like doing the division beforehand and working out the number of days beforehand is also something I have tried - however, I haven't seen a noticeable decrease in the time needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work:

```
df = foo.copy() # copy foo to new df
df['date'] = [pd.date_range(s, e, freq='d') for s, e in zip(pd.to_datetime(df['start_date']), pd.to_datetime(df['end_date']))] # create DatetimeIndex from start date and end date
df['quantity'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.quantity/len(x.date), axis=1) # calculate quantity per date 
df = df.explode('date').drop(['start_date', 'end_date'], axis=1) # explode by date
```

Output `df.head()`:

|  | index | quantity | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 7.14286 | 2019-09-30 00:00:00 |
| 0 | 1 | 7.14286 | 2019-10-01 00:00:00 |
| 0 | 1 | 7.14286 | 2019-10-02 00:00:00 |
| 0 | 1 | 7.14286 | 2019-10-03 00:00:00 |
| 0 | 1 | 7.14286 | 2019-10-04 00:00:00 |

Comment: Really nice answer - create a list in the df then explode from there. Thanks! For anyone using this if you have 0 values in the quantity, you would need to add a condition in the lambda or do the division beforehand